# When to use a workflow engine - use and misuse

Tags: workflow, batch-processing, jbpm, rule-engine, business-process-management

THE CONTEXT:

I should develop a software to calculate billing for a lot of customers
The software should be used by different local administrations, each one with its own rules to calculate the billing to its citizens.
At first i've thought to a workflow engine in order to "design" different calculation flows and apply then to the customers.

In the past i had a little experience with a workflow manager product (i worked a little with IBM BPM) and i had a lot of difficult to debug what happens when something went wrong and i found a lot of performance issue (respect to a simple OOP software).
Maybe these difficulties went caused by my poor knowledge of the tool, or maybe IBM BPM is not as good as IBM says.

Anyway, respect to my objective (produce a custom billing, and make it as flexible as possible in therm of configuration and process) is a workflow engine a suitable product?
Any suggestion about tools, frameworks and above all how to approach the problem.

My initial idea of the architecture is to develop a main software in c# (where i'm more confident) and using a workflow engine (like JBpm) as a black box, invoking previously configured flows into the bpm.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) for your use case. It records all events that are related to your workflow in an execution history. It makes troubleshooting of production issues very straightforward.

As workflow is essentially a program in Java (or Go) you have unlimited flexibility on implementation. The performance is also not an issue as Cadence was built from ground up for high scalability. It was tested to over hundred million open workflows and tens of thousands of events per second.

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.